# Open office Assign a number to a color

Tags: openoffice-calc

What I'm trying to do is calculate the number of hours worked according to the color and the person, all of this to be determined in the **nombre d'heures** column in front of each person.

Knowing that **matin** is in orange and corresponds to 2 a.m., that **midi** is in white and corresponds to 1 a.m., and that **nuit** is in green and corresponds to 8 a.m.

and that Catherine, Sarah, Irene or Laurence can be morning, evening or night.

I use Mac os 10.15.7
OpenOffice 4.1.9

[image: Spreadsheet]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SU. I'd suggest you specify what exactly is behind that "Look here" -link. Not many people are keen to download a random file anyway so I think in this case a better option is taking a screenshot of the appropriate part of your sheet, and adding as separate text entries what exact formula(s) in which cell(s) you have tried so far to resolve the issue. That should get the ball rolling. As it is, this is a bit confusing.

Comment: OK your question is much clearer now :-) Can you please also add to the question what exactly is the input, what formulas you use in which cells, what exactly is the result you want to see, and what's the result you actually do see? That's sort of a must - you will get help in determining why your formulas fail but nobody is likely to write them for you.

Comment: Precisely my problem is that I can not find a formula which allows me to display in the column "Numbers of hours" the hours that each person made